# Pagination for sub-pages

Tags: pagination, pages

I have a top level page with a lot of subpages.

When a user visits the top level page they currently see the titles/thumbnails/excerpts of **all** of the subpages.

How can I paginate the display of the subpages so that **only** 3 are displayed at a time, giving the user the ability to navigate via the typcial "< Previous  1,2,3,4,5 Next >" pagination menu?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you actually insert the titles/thumbnails/excerpts of the subpages manually using the post editor?

If so, you can place the `<!--next page-->` tag in between every three subpages, and they will be split into paginated sections. (Use the HTML editor to insert the tag.)

Keep in mind that many people do not like pagination, so doing this could potentially drive visitors away from your site.

Answer (score 1):

You should use, wp_link_pages function.

When you writing an article use this syntax;

```
<!--nextpage-->
```

Than add this line where ypu want to display your pagination links in your single.php file;

```
<?php wp_link_pages('before=<p>&after=</p>&next_or_number=number&pagelink=page %'); ?>
```

You can get more description about the funcstion on [Codex pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages).